Measurement Reference PSpice/LTspice
I have been using LTspice previously for my designs, recently I have encountered an issue. I have a design with a GND reference as seen in the picture and I want to measure the voltage across the 5 Ω shunt resistor (so in reference to the virtual GND). Is there a way I can achieve this in PSpice or LTspice? The voltage across the shunt when referenced to the virtual GND is 5 V but in my simulation its not 5 V as the package references it to the GND and not the virtual GND (NB: I have labeled the virtual GND myself).


If you want to plot Rshunt's voltage, you could always plot I(Shunt)*5

Please pick a part number for your NMOS.  Default NMOS model has a threshold voltage of zero volts.  No bueno.

Yes,
After you have run the simulation, right click on the wire you want that net to become your reference and select "Mark Reference" from the dropdown menu.
Now all voltages are given relative to that net.

Thank you. But this only solves the visualization of the results relative to the reference but it doesnt solve the problem. E.g say that the voltage above the shunt is 35V and 30V below it. This would mean that the voltage drop is 5V across the shunt and this is the voltage I want to measure and feed into the other RC circuit. From the current design I have attached, the input into the MOSFET would be 35V and not the 5V across the shunt. I hope I am making sense.

What is "the other RC circuit"? The original question is about measuring the drop across the resistor. Feeding that voltage to another circuit is another question entirely.

@Kabza Yes, I agree with the above comment.  I sounds like you don't want to "measure" the voltage but utilize it in your circuit, which is not what "measure" means.  Luckily, the method utilizing the VCVS (i.e. an "E-source") in GodJihyo's answer lets you do both.

Add a voltage controlled voltage source (VCVS) to your schematic.
Connect the inputs of the VCVS to the points you want to measure across.
Connect the negative output of the VCVS to ground.
Set the value of the VCVS to 1. This gives the VCVS a gain of 1 so the output voltage follows the input voltage.
Take your measurement at the positive output of the VCVS. The output voltage from the VCVS can be used in your circuit as well. It basically just takes a differential input voltage and converts it to a single ended ground referenced output voltage.
You can see this done in my answer to this question.
Also note that for a virtual ground you can use the COM symbol, place a ground, right click it and change to COM. This doesn’t make it the reference, it just lets you tie points together with a symbol the same way a label does. You can make it the reference by using the technique @blup1980 mentioned.

In LTspice, you can measure the voltage across a component.
Put the cursor on the net above the 5 ohm resistor. You should see a red probe.
Hold down the left mouse button and move the cursor to net below the 5 ohm resistor. You should see a black probe.
Release the left mouse button and you'll have the voltage across the 5 ohm resistor plotted.
If you give the nets net names, you can manually add a trace in the graph.
Example: V(a,b)
